# Скажите как сделать чтобы при клике кнопки мыши открывался текст?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Как сделать не через select а через div ? И чтобы стрелки менялись вверх и вниз

Как при клике сделать чтобы фон элемента менялся,  я написал и у меня меняет фон только как сделать чтобы он при клике на следующем элементе менял его фон а предыдущему возвращал его фон до клика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image]

```js
var dropdown__label = document.querySelector('.dropdown__label');
dropdown__label.onclick = function(){
 dropdown__label.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```css
.s-select {
  margin-top: 37px; }

form {
  background-color: #fff; }

.select {
  color: #000;
  width: 290px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 29px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px; }

.select .option:hover {
  color: #e41645;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow-y: auto; }

.select .option:active {
  background-color: #fff; }

.selectbox .select:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: 0 -10px; }

.selectize-control.single .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input input {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px; }

.selectize-control.single .selectize-input, .selectize-control.single .selectize-input input:hover {
  background-color: #fff; }

.selectize-dropdown, .selectize-input, .selectize-input input {
  background-color: #fff; }

.select__title {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 73px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4; }

.seli {
  margin-top: 100px; }

.select-block {
  margin-left: 70px; }
```

```html
<section class="s-select">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <form action="#" method="post">
      <select size="1" name="hero[]" class='select' id='select-beast'>
        <option class='option' disabled>LOW / MID-RISE</option>
        <option class='option'>ACRA Mid-rise MMR</option>
        <option class='option'>Muse Mid-rise MRL </option>
        <option class='option'>Solon Premium Mid-rise MRL</option>
     </select>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стилизуете уж сами :)

Стрелка делается точно также, отслеживаниее появление `dropdown_open` и поворачиваете стрелку: `transform: rotate(180deg)`

```js
class Dropdown {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onLabel = this.onLabel.bind(this);

    this.label = this.node.querySelector(".dropdown__label");

    this.label.addEventListener("click", this.onLabel, false);
  }

  isOpen() {
    return this.node.classList.contains("dropdown_open");
  }

  onLabel() {
    this.isOpen() ? this.node.classList.remove("dropdown_open") : this.node.classList.add("dropdown_open");
  }
}

[...document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown")].forEach(node => new Dropdown(node));
```

```css
.dropdown_open .dropdown__list {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown__list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__label">Some text</div>
  <ul class="dropdown__list">
    <li class="dropdown__item">Some text #2</li>
    <li class="dropdown__item">Some Text #3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__label">Some text</div>
  <ul class="dropdown__list">
    <li class="dropdown__item">Some text #2</li>
    <li class="dropdown__item">Some Text #3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое бро

Comment: @user332017, если Вам помог ответ, то отметьте его галочкой, это поможет будущим посетителям сразу найти ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: @user332017 разве не нужно, чтобы по клику на дочерний элемент ul он был выбран? Вы кажется в вопросе дали пример с select, а он как правило, нужен когда нужно, что-то выбрать. Я имею ввиду конкретно пример, который является решением

Comment: @meine спасибо, отключил gulpfile и все заработало т

Comment: @meine  Здравствуйте в поиске решения проблемы наткнулся на Ваш код хочу попросить Вас что бы вы его улучшили чтобы при клике можно было выбрать несколько элементов ?

Comment: @meine у меня не хватает знаний и опыта сделать самому :(((

Comment: @xes, в плане "несколько элементов", а щас как?)

Comment: @meine извините уже решил проблему